# Why my code is not printing the sorted array?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

Why the code isn't printing anything? what this code is supposed to do is sorting the 2d array in that way:
the 2d array represents a {x,y}, then the code needs to sort it, the rows which contain x < 0 need to be first and the rows with x>=0 need to be next.
the swap function here is to swap between two rows. now when I try printing the sorted array, I get nothing in the output

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int p1[], int p2[]);
int arrange(int p[][2], int n);


void swap(int p1[], int p2[]){
  for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    int temp=p1[i];
    p1[i]=p2[i];
    p2[i]=temp;
  }
}

int arrange(int p[][2], int n){
  int idx=0;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    if(p[i][0] >= 0 && (i+1)<n)
        if(p[i+1][0] <0) {
            swap(&p[i][0],&p[i+1][0]);
            idx++;
        }
    else if(p[i][0]<0)
        idx++;
  }
return 1;
}

int main()
{
  int a[4][2]={{1,2},{6,7},{-10,5},{0,1}};
  arrange(a[4][2], 4);
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        printf("{%d, %d}, ", a[i][0], a[i][1] );
  }

}
```

Comment: `arrange(a[4][2], 4);` should be   `arrange(a, 4);`

Comment: Yes, take the compiler's warnings serious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the code isn't printing anything?

Because it doesn't compile, since your compiler should give errors and a warning.

In order to fix the errors, change this:

```
arrange(a[4][2], 4);
```

to that:

```
arrange(a, 4);
```

---

Appendix:

Here is what warning GCC with `Wall` flag passed to it gave me:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int arrange(int (*)[2], int)':
prog.cc:17:7: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous 'else' [-Wdangling-else]
17 |     if(p[i][0] >= 0 && (i+1)<n)
   |
```

In order to fix that warning, I changed your code to:

```
if(p[i][0] >= 0 && (i+1)<n) {
    if(p[i+1][0] <0) {
        swap(&p[i][0],&p[i+1][0]);
        idx++;
    }
} else if(p[i][0]<0) {
    idx++;
}
```